# How to use "nodes" in Jetty Overlay Deployer?

Tags: jetty, overlay, nodes

I have been researching Jetty Overlay Deployer. (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Configuring_the_Jetty_Overlay_Deployer). This page pretty much explains exactly how to use this feature. Unfortunately, it does not talk about "nodes". Does any one more how to use the "nodes" feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node feature is just another layer of overrides.  So you have the base webapp, then you overlay that to make a template, which is overlayed with node specific configuration, which is finally overlayed with instance specific configuration.

So when instantiating the OverlayAppProvider you set a node name and then that is always used to look for an overlay a node overlay.

Note we have not yet ported the overlay deployer to jetty-9, but we will: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404508

Comment: This is useful. Do you know what is the time-frame for this feature? Is your team thinking about simplifying the whole Overlay architecture? Since many vendors are moving towards SaaS model, it would be nice, if you can implement the Overlay feature with multi-tenancy in mind. (i.e. Running multiple independent webapps with common libraries and resources that can be shared between these webapps in an efficient manner).

Comment: overlay deployer as been added to jetty 9 and will show up in 9.0.4, if you have requests for features please open an issue at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty or use the developer mailing list